# Showing a loading screen during fragment switching

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm trying to show a loading screen (ACR.Dialogs) while showing a new fragment, tried the following code however, the loading popup doesnt show; i know that i should be using threading however this is a click event, `

```
private void buttonloginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("Wait Please");
        FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ActiveJobs activeJobs = new ActiveJobs();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.ll_frameLayout, activeJobs, "activeJobs");
        FragmentManager.PopBackStack();
        ft.AddToBackStack(null);
        ft.Commit();
    }`
```

Whats the way to show a loading screen while switching fragments?

Comment: could you show your whole code in activity,i work well on my side

Comment: even in a click event without an asynchronous thread you cannot achieve this